# How to export view as multiple images in Revit API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, revit

Is it possible to export a view as more than 1 image? in any kind of split.

When exporting the view as an Image I want to keep the scaling consistent and Revit will not allow export an image with more than 15000 pixels. So on big Models I want to split the image to keep the meter per pixel consistent.

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by cropping different parts of the view and hiding everything outside the crop before the export. As the image export only export the visible elements.

I've encountered a different issue now, there are different visible objects outside of the actual model that interfere with the image export, sometimes those are elevation markers, site internal origin, other hidden annotations and many more.

Is there a way to hide absolutely everything outside the crop? do I need to go over every instance of a list of possible visible objects and hide them?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any such possibility.

Please be aware of the following rule of thumb:

In general, if a feature is not available in the Revit product manually through the user interface, then the Revit API will not provide it either.

You should therefore research the optimal workflow and best practices to address your task at hand manually through the Revit user interface first.

To do so, please discuss and analyse it with an experienced application engineer, product usage expert, or product support.

Once you have got that part sorted out, it is time to step up into the programming environment.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jeremy.

Comment: Added an answer and another question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing your solution to the original question on exporting several images displaying different elements by toggling their visibilities.

Regarding your second, new, question, on interfering elements such as 'elevation markers, site internal origin, other hidden annotations and many more':

Yes, indeed, I would suggest hiding those as well, just as you successfully handled the other 'standard' BIM elements, e.g., using the [`HideElements` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/6b0ae8d1-776a-ad0d-577d-ffdc11673019.htm), `HideElementsTemporary`, or, maybe better still for such special element types, hiding their entire categories using [`HideCategoriesTemporary`](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/2f59330d-a69d-a78b-e364-f22b087960ef.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've managed to hide everything but the internal origin, I can't seems to "catch" it. The way I hide it manually is selecting a floor plan (view) then going to View -> Visibility / Graphics -> Site -> uncheck internal origin. How do I hide it via the code (for a specific view)? 

Another issue I'm trying to solve is how do I check if there is an empty cropbox? sometimes due to the nature of the image splitting some images can be empty, contain no elements at all and I'd like to filter them out however I couldn't find an easy way to check if a cropbox is empty.

Comment: I found how to hide the internal origin, their category is OST_IOS_GeoLocations and hidding those categories using  HideCategoriesTemporary worked. Still trying to figure out how to check if a cropbox is empty without itterating over all elements geometry.